# babel5 --> babel6: modules property

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

i'm trying to figure out how to tell babel6 to generate a particular module syntax (amd, commonjs, etc)

this is how i used to specify the module: https://github.com/aurelia/metadata/blob/master/build/tasks/build.js#L48

```
gulp.task('build-commonjs', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.output + jsName)
    .pipe(to5(assign({}, compilerOptions, {modules:'common'})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output + 'commonjs'));
});

gulp.task('build-amd', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.output + jsName)
    .pipe(to5(assign({}, compilerOptions, {modules:'amd'})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output + 'amd'));
});
```

babel6 gives me the error: `Unknow option: base.modules`

appreciate any guidance !! :)

---

error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\a\au\metadata\dist\aurelia-metadata.js: Unknown option: base.modules
    at Logger.error (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:262:18)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:416:10)
    at File.initOptions (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:191:75)
    at new File (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:122:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp-babel\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:42:16)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp-babel\index.js:32:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:160:12)
    at doWrite (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:335:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:321:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:248:11)
    at write (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (C:\a\au\metadata\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:664:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
```

Comment: if you are developing using aurelia framework. use typescript which is very compatible

Comment: hi @Venkatraman - i'm working on upgrading the aurelia build process to use babel6 from babel5.  This is how the aurelia .d.ts files get generated from the ES7 source code.  i'm 100% with you on TypeScript :) :)

Comment: update the exact and full error from babeljs in the question to proceed further

Comment: repo (branch) is here: https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/metadata/tree/babel6-upgrade

`npm install` then `gulp build` to reproduce error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from @thedark1337 in [babeljs slack](https://babeljs.slack.com/messages/plugins/):

For babel 6 you need to use plugins

> - https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-amd
> - https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/
> - https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-systemjs/

also if you haven't, you'll need babel-preset-es2015 as well to transpile from ES2015 to ES5